# Position a LinearLayout (horizontal center)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem positioning a `LinearLayout`. See image for the problem. If I use `wrap_content` in the field specified, it is not centered. If I use `match_parent`, it is centered, but the components are spaced too far apart. How do I 'wrap' the contents, but center the layout horizontally? (vertical is not a consideration here)

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"  !!! (or match_parent)
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="25dip"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/game1CheckButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/checkbutton"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="clickCheck"
        android:src="@drawable/checkbutton" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/game1Step"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:contentDescription="@string/game1step1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/game1NextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nextbutton"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="clickNext"
        android:src="@drawable/nextbutton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand, you want 3 obects all positioned in the horizontal center, no matter the vertical position.

So, I'd do that like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="25dip"
    >
    <!-- The center object -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/game1Step"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/game1step1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />
    <!-- The left object -->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/game1CheckButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/game1Step"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/checkbutton"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="clickCheck"
        android:src="@drawable/checkbutton"
    />
    <!-- The right object -->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/game1NextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/game1Step"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nextbutton"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="clickNext"
        android:src="@drawable/nextbutton"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```